# Activate a DC motor for a fixed amount of time

Tags: motor

I have a single simple DC motor that upon a condition I wish to let it run for 3 minute. How can I do it in Arduino? a simple addition to the code will be great help.

As I use Adafruit motor shield this is my current code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MotorShield.h>
#include "utility/Adafruit_PWMServoDriver.h"

Adafruit_MotorShield AFMS = Adafruit_MotorShield(); 
Adafruit_DCMotor *myMotor = AFMS.getMotor(1);

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);           // set up Serial library at 9600 bps
   AFMS.begin();  // create with the default frequency 1.6KHz
}

void loop() {
IOvalue = 1000

if (IOvalue = 1000) { 

 //this is the motor I wish to run for 3 min 
   myMotor->setSpeed(25); 
   myMotor->run(FORWARD); 
   delay(100); 
 }  
}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MotorShield.h>
#include "utility/Adafruit_PWMServoDriver.h"

Adafruit_MotorShield AFMS = Adafruit_MotorShield(); 
Adafruit_DCMotor *myMotor = AFMS.getMotor(1);
boolean motorRunning = false;
unsigned long motorStartMillis;
unsigned long motorRunMillis = 180000;

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);           // set up Serial library at 9600 bps
   AFMS.begin();  // create with the default frequency 1.6KHz
}

void loop() {
  IOvalue = 1000

  if (IOvalue = 1000) {
    //this is the motor I wish to run for 3 min 
    myMotor->setSpeed(25); 
    myMotor->run(FORWARD); 
    motorStartMillis = millis();
    motorRunning = true;
  }

  // check if motor is running and time-to-run has elapsed
  if( motorRunning && (millis()-motorStartMillis > motorRunMillis) )
  {
    myMotor->setSpeed(0); 
    myMotor->run(RELEASE);
    motorRunning = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
long int currentMillis;
void setup() {
    pinMode(motorPin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(motorPin, LOW);
}
void loop() {
    if(condition is met){
        startOfMotor = millis();
        while(millis() != (startOfMotor+180000)){
            digitalWrite(motorPin, HIGH);
        }
    digitalWrite(motorPin, LOW);
    }
}
```

This `motorPin` is the pin to which the motor is connected. `millis()` gets the milliseconds after the board is started. 3 min = 180 seconds = 180000 ms.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that I use Adafruit motor shield and therefore how can I integrate you code into this snippet.

Code:
void loop() {
…..
….
if (IOvalue = 1000) {
//this is the motor I wish to run for 3 min
  myMotor->setSpeed(25); 
  myMotor->run(FORWARD);
   delay(100);
   }
}

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code? It is hard to read it in comments.

Comment: About the shield.. I need to know more about your setup.

Comment: Updated the question and embedded the code.

Comment: I have no idea about the Adafruit motor shield. Sorry! (For such simple operations you are better off using the Arduino itself. )